# WPF ToolTip Visibility Binding to RadioButton Checked

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, wpf-controls

I want to show/hide tooltips on radio buttons based on which radio button in a different group is checked. I tried the BooleanToVisibilityConverter and it works for other Controls, but not ToolTips.

```
<Page.Resources>
    <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="b2v" />
</Page.Resources>
```

Radio buttons to determine if the tooltip is visible. `ToolTip` should be visible when "InputText" is checked.

```
<RadioButton x:Name="InputText" Content="InputText" IsChecked="True" />
<RadioButton x:Name="Other" Content="Other" />
```

Radio button with tooltip

```
<RadioButton x:Name="InputRows" Content="Rows">
    <RadioButton.ToolTip>
        <ToolTip x:Name="InputRowsToolTip"
                 Visibility="{Binding IsChecked,ElementName=InputText, Converter={StaticResource b2v}}">
            ToolTip text here
        </ToolTip>
    </RadioButton.ToolTip>
</RadioButton>
```

Other things I've tried that don't work:

- Wrap the tooltip text in a `<TextBlock>` and include the Visibility parameter there - no effect.
- Use `<TextBlock>` instead of `<ToolTip>` and include the Visibility parameter there - no effect.
- Add `ToolTipService.ShowOnDisabled="False"` and `ToolTipService.IsEnabled="False"` to ToolTip and RadioButton - tooltip does not show at all.

I can get it to behave the way I want with methods in the cs file for `InputTextRadioButton_Checked` and `OtherRadioButton_Checked` and set the `InputRowsToolTip.Visibility = Visibility.Visible` or `Visibility.Collapsed` depending on RadioButton, but it seems like I should be able to do this with the BooleanToVisibilityConverter since it works for other Controls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Just added `DataContext` in InputRows

```xml
DataContext="{Binding ElementName=InputText"
```

And Your code.

```xml
<RadioButton x:Name="InputText" Content="InputText" IsChecked="True" />
<RadioButton x:Name="Other" Content="Other" />

<RadioButton x:Name="InputRows" Content="Rows" DataContext="{Binding ElementName=InputText}">
    <RadioButton.ToolTip>
        <ToolTip x:Name="InputRowsToolTip"
                 Visibility="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=DataContext.IsChecked, Converter={StaticResource b2v}}">
            ToolTip text here
        </ToolTip>
    </RadioButton.ToolTip>
</RadioButton>
```

The control inside the tooltip area of the radio button does not directly find the control outside. That's why I think it's better to deal with it through DataContext, a powerful Dependency Property.

You cannot use the form below.

- `ElementName`
- `RelativeSource AncestorType`
- `Relative Source TemplateParent`

this sample sourcecode
https://github.com/ncoresoftsource/stackoverflowsample/tree/main/src/answers/radiobutton-tooltip-other-binding

Comment: It does not work. The ToolTips are still visible regardless of which radio button is selected.

Comment: @LisaB I confirmed that the sample source code is made and executed. Do you want me to attach the sample source code?

Comment: https://github.com/ncoresoftsource/stackoverflowsample/tree/main/src/answers/radiobutton-tooltip-other-binding

Comment: If there is anything I missed, please tell me!

Comment: Thank you! The code in your github worked. The code in your original answer was missing "DataContext" in "Path=DataContext.IsChecked".

Comment: @LisaB I'm so sorry!! Thank you.